# Adding popover data-content inside HTML page, Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I use Twitter Bootstrap 2.0.1. I have such a button:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" rel="popover"
  title="today 12:11"
  data-content="I'm the content of the button 1 heyoo">Last text</a>
<a class="btn btn-info" rel="popover"
  title="yesterday 10:20"
  data-content="I'm the content of the button 2 heyoo">Last text</a>
```

But when I use this code, search engines doesn't take "data-content" into account. But I want "data-content" to be seen by spiders.

If I make this, button becomes to big:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" rel="popover"
  title="today 12:11">I'm the content of the button 1 heyoo</a>
```

This is also alternative, but creates duplicate data:

```
<a class="btn btn-info" rel="popover"
  title="today 12:11"
  data-content="I'm the content of the button 1 heyoo">
  Last text
 <div style="display: none;">
 <span>I'm the content of the button 1 heyoo</span>
 </div>
</a>
```

Another alternative is putting "data-content" into page but writing it with font 1 point. But I don't think that's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

> But when I use this code, search engines doesn't take "data-content" into account.

Why should they?

What would be the benefit of a search engine directing me to your site, when the text *“I'm the content of the button 1 heyoo”* that I searched for is not displayed in a readable fashion to me on that page?

Comment: You can read the content if you hover your mouse on the button. That's how popover button works.

Comment: Then it’s relevant info, and should be in appropriate HTML elements – not just in some attribute that I won’t see if f.e. I visit that page with JS and/or CSS deactivated. And for mobile devices that don’t have hover capabilities, you will most likely want a different presentation of this content anyway.